# Can't handle chrome/firefox login popup window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I just started working on an automation framework for a `asp.net` app using `selenium webdriver` with `C#`. When I go to the url, a login pop-up is displayed asking for credentials(username, password).

I have been able to handle this on `IE`, using

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mywebsite.com");  
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials(@"ad\username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```

However, this solution doesn't work for `Firefox` or `Chrome`. 
I also tried

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mywebsite.com");  
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SendKeys(@"ad\username");
alert.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
alert.SendKeys("password");
alert.Accept();
```

and

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IAlert alert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
```

and this doesn't seem to work either.

Is anyone has any idea of how should I approach this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for Firefox using AutoIT and following this tutorial [Handle windows authentication in Selenium Webdriver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=civzNtKTCD0).